# Gracefully recover from parse error in lxml

Tags: python, xml, parsing, exception, lxml

I want to continue parsing an invalid XML file, but capture the number of invalid files in a variable. Trying this:

```
    try:
        parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=False)
        tree = etree.parse(rawfile, parser=parser)
        print "Good XML!"
    except etree.XMLSyntaxError:
        parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
        tree = etree.parse(rawfile, parser=parser)
        print "Bad XML!"
        misformattedXMLFile += 1

    root = tree.getroot()
```

But when an exception is raised, even though the "except" clause is correctly visited, the "root" element does not get set (it is "None"). If I run this without any try/except, just with "recover=True", root is set correctly and the file is processed. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete for a functional test that works and shows your problem. I've imported the module you forgot, create a missformatted `xml` file, declare the `misformattedXMLFile` variable without touching nothing else, and it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you Birei for responding. Actually the problem was that "rawfile" (the source XML file from which I took XML data) was opened **before** the try/except blocks. This created a problem, because once the "try" block used the rawfile, it was not in the same state in the "except" block, and this confused the entire code further down.

I fixed this by moving the file opening routine into the try/except blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`finally`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally)

```
try:
   #something
except etree.XMLSyntaxError:
    #onotherthing

finally:
    root = tree.getroot()
```